# Is it possible to simulate Azure Websites locally for testing?

Tags: php, azure, testing, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

We're developing a dynamic website that is to be hosted on Azure Websites. Before going to the staging phase, I'd like to test it locally in an environment that is as similar to the production environment as possible. (By testing I mean clicking around and checking that things work, nothing fancy.)

Right now we're doing this with standard Apache, MySQL and PHP installations, but I fear that things that work on this setup might not work on the live web server (Azure Websites).

Ideally, we'd use our own computers to run virtual machines that would be exactly like the production server we will be deploying to. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, is there another way that is better than what we're currently doing?

Comment: the SDK comes with "Compute Emulator" for just this purpose

Comment: Compute emulator doesn't emulate Azure Websites - it provides emulation for Cloud Services (Web Role or Worker Role).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will be to perform a test deployment to an Azure Website instance.  There isn't a local emulator or replica for Azure Websites and Azure Websites are more than just a vanilla instance of IIS.

To provide you with the best chance of success I would recommend:

1. Replace Apache with IIS locally.
2. Ensure the version of PHP you are using aligns with a supported versions on Azure Websites.  Deploy the PHP "runtime" on your IIS setup locally.
3. MySQL - again check supported versions align with the version you are running. This isn't embedded in the Azure Websites feature - you could run your own on a VM or leverage one from ClearDB.